# ReferenceError: Cannot initialise user (entity) before initialization

Tags: express, typeorm

I've defined 3 entities - `user`, `company` and `companyuser` in my express app using typeorm. On compilation, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'User' before initialization
    at file:///C:/Users/Yu/Desktop/Projects/keytest/keytest-backend/models/CompanyUser.ts:23:9
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

The error comes from the ManyToOne decorator for the user field in the CompanyUser entity, as commenting out that line gets rid of the error

User entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => CompanyUser, companyUser => companyUser.user, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  companyUsers: CompanyUser[];
}
```

Company entity:

```
export class Company extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => CompanyUser, companyUser => companyUser.company)
  companyUsers: CompanyUser[];
}
```

CompanyUser entity:

```
export class CompanyUser extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  
  @Column({ default: false })
  isVerified: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isDisabled: boolean;
  
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
  
  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.companyUsers)
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, company => company.companyUsers)
  company: Company;
}
```

The datasource:

```
const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT as unknown as number,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    entities: [User, Company, CompanyUser],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a circular dependency between my User and CompanyUser entities, hence the error. To fix it, I added a relation wrapper.

According to the typeorm [docs](https://typeorm.io/faq#how-to-use-typeorm-in-esm-projects):

> Doing this prevents the type of the property from being saved in the transpiled code in the property metadata, preventing circular dependency issues.

Just remember to **not** use the Relation wrapper on non-relation column types.

So the CompanyUser entity becomes:

```
@Entity()
export class CompanyUser extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  
  @Column({ default: false })
  isVerified: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isDisabled: boolean;
  
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
  
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.companyUsers)
  user: Relation<User>;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.companyUsers)
  company: Company;
}
```